# Como retornar valor de atributo X - em um ManyToManyField

Tags: python-3.x, django, orm

Eu tenho algumas classes que se relacionam entre si. Ex: tenho uma class Atividades_estruturas_complementares que tem uma relação m2m com uma class Atividade. E tenho uma outra class estruturas_complementares que tem um 1to1
com Atividades_estruturas_complementares e com uma segunda class Passivo, onde faço uma inclusão inline no admin. Esse é meu contexto e abaixo está os respectivos codes.

Atividade:

```py
    class Atividade(models.Model):
        codigoSICRO = models.OneToOneField(Sicro, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True, primary_key=True)
        nome = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=200, unique=True)
        descricao = models.TextField('Descrição', max_length=300, blank=True)
        unidadeMedida = models.ForeignKey(Unidade, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

Lista de Atividades de Estruturas Complementares:

```py
    class Atividade_estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
        atividades_complementares = models.ManyToManyField(Atividade)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
            verbose_name = 'Estruturas Complementares'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.atividades_complementares.nome
```

Estruturas Complementares:

```py
    class Estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                                 related_name='complementares',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    atividade = models.OneToOneField(Atividade_estruturas_complementares, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='atividade_estruturas_complementares')
    comprimento = models.DecimalField(
        'Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    largura_altura = models.DecimalField(
        'Largura / Altura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    profundidade = models.DecimalField(
        'Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estruturas Complementares'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
```

Diante dessa situação na class Atividade_estruturas_complementares eu gostaria de retornar o nome da atividade que se encontra na class atividade, mas não estou conseguindo, pois não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso. O exemplo:

```py
    def __str__(self):
            return self.atividades_complementares.nome
```

retorna o seguinte erro no tamplate:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha ideia em criar essa estrutura é restringir a inclusão de atividades que não estão relacionadas. Por isso a class intermediária.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso precisem de mais alguma informação estou a disposição. E como sou estagiário e sem nenhuma pessoa da área com experiencia para auxiliar estou aberto a todo e qualquer tipo de sugestão para melhor implementar
essa solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, minha solução foi ao invés de usar o m2m foi usar 1to1 na class atividades_estruturas_complementares, ficando assim:

```
class Atividade_estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
atividades_complementares = models.OneToOneField(Atividade, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                                 related_name='atividades_complementares')

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
    verbose_name = 'Estruturas Complementares'

def __str__(self):
    return self.atividades_complementares.nome
```

Já na class Estruturas_complementares eu tive que alterar o campo de 1to1 para um foreignKey como pode ver abaixo.

```
class Estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
passivo_id = models.ForeignKey(Passivo,
                             related_name='complementares',
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
atividade_complementar = models.ForeignKey(Atividade_estruturas_complementares, on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                 related_name='atividade_estruturas_complementares')
comprimento = models.DecimalField(
    'Comprimento', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
largura_altura = models.DecimalField(
    'Largura / Altura', max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
profundidade = models.DecimalField(
    'Profundidade', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Estruturas Complementares'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
    unique_together = (('passivo_id', 'atividade_complementar'),)

def __str__(self):
    return self.atividade_complementar.atividades_complementares.nome
```

dessa maneira foi possível conseguir o que eu gostaria.

Answer (score 1):

Boas numa relação m2m, podes utilizar assim:

**models.py**

```
class Atividade_estruturas_complementares(models.Model):
        atividades_complementares = models.ManyToManyField(Atividade)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Estruturas Complementares'
            verbose_name = 'Estruturas Complementares'

        @property
        def m2m_nome(self):
            return self.atividades_complementares.nome
```

**admin.py**

```
list_display = ('m2m_nome',)
```

NOTA: Existem algumas limitações com o ManyRelatedManager, verifica aqui este [topico](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21763).

Comment: na realidade usando o m2m não vou ter como fazer o que eu quero. vou ter que utilizar um 1to1. mas obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim Ernesto

Comment: Pois, por isso coloquei o link de limitações. Contudo, para **consulta** da tabela, podes utilizar da forma que indiquei.

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar da forma que indicou, mas no meu caso não resolveu da maneira como eu gostaria. Mas ajudou a entender melhor o que eu queria e elaborar uma solução mais eficiente para o meu caso. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Oi, partilha então a tua solução assim podes ajudar alguém no futuro. Vota como útil a minha resposta, caso ela tenha ajudado, apesar de não ser a solução.

Comment: Demorei mas vim colocar a minha solução. Obrigado pelo dica.